# Polynomial roots comparison

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does there exist a quadratic polynomial $x^2 + px + q$ with the property that $p$
and $q$ can be changed by no more than 0.01 so that at least one of the roots of the polynomial
changes by at least 100?

Work:
The roots are 
$$x_1=\frac{p_1\pm\sqrt{p_1^2-4q_1}}{2}$$
$$x_2=\frac{p_2\pm\sqrt{p_2^2-4q_2}}{2}$$
Since they are talking about the "leftmost" or"rightmost" roots, we prove
$$\bigg|\frac{p_2-p_1+\sqrt{p_2^2-4q_2}-\sqrt{p_1^2-4q_1}}{2}\bigg|<100$$
WLOG,
$$\frac{\sqrt{p_2^2-4q_2}-\sqrt{p_1^2-4q_1}}{2}<99.9$$
How can I prove this. The square roots are tricky to deal with.

Comment: You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: Start writting the roots of the quadratic. Then add an epsilon to "p" and write them again. Then, think a little on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the original roots with $x_1,x_2$, and the roots after change with $y_1,y_2$.

By the Viete equations, to get similar coefficients you need
\begin{align}
x_1+x_2\approx y_1+y_2\\
x_1x_2\approx y_1y_2
\end{align}

if you change one root by $100$, $y_1=x_1+100$, you have to change the other root by about $-100$, $y_2\approx x_2-100$ for the first relation. Then the second gives $$x_1x_2\approx (x_1+100)(x_2-100)\implies x_2-x_1\approx 100.$$

But this would make $x_2\approx x_1+100\approx y_1$, which means that the root set has not really changed, only the position of the root has switched.

---

Or in other words, the roots of a polynomial are continuous functions of the coefficients, and if the roots are simple this relation is smooth (analytical).
Consider the factorization into linear factors of the modified polynomial
$$
(x-(x_1+Δx_1))(x-(x_2+Δx_2))=x^2+(p+Δp)x+(q+Δq)
$$
Insert $x=x_1$ and $x=x_2$, the roots of the original polynomial,
$$
Δx_1(x_2-x_1+Δx_2)=Δp\,x_1+Δq,~~
Δx_2(x_1-x_2+Δx_1)=Δp\,x_2+Δq.
$$
If $Δp,Δq$ on the right side are small, esp. small against $|x_2-x_1|$, then $Δx_1,Δx_2$ have to be likewise small, in first approximation they  are the Weierstraß updates (see Durand-Kerner method)
$$
Δx_1=-\frac{Δp\,x_1+Δq}{x_1-x_2},~~Δx_2=-\frac{Δp\,x_2+Δq}{x_2-x_1}.
$$